# Inseting/Updating image to SQL Server database by reading from a directory

Tags: java, sql-server, image, primefaces, blob

I am trying to insert/update image(or BLOB) to a table and the column has data type IMAGE in SQL Server 2012. The source is a file directory which has all the images and is named according to the PRIMARY KEY of the table.
I need to read all the files by only selecting the directory and bulk insert/update to the table respective rows.
If possible please suggest an example in Primefaces with dialog box to select the directory.

My code for single file upload is :

```
private byte[] resizeImage(byte[] imgBytes) {
BufferedImage originalImage = null;
try {
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes);
System.out.println("FILE SIZE BEFORE RESIZE IS "+is.available());
originalImage = ImageIO.read(is);
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
int type = originalImage.getType() == 0 ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : originalImage.getType();

BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(192, 192, type);//set width and height of image
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, 192, 192, null);
g.dispose();

// BufferedImage to ByteArrayInputStream
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
ImageIO.write(resizedImage, "jpg", os);
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("FILE SIZE AFTER RESIZE IS "+os.size());
return os.toByteArray();
}
```

And I have :

```
public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {  
try {
if (validateImage(event.getFile()))
{
memberImage = new DefaultStreamedContent(event.getFile().getInputstream(), "image/jpeg");
memberInformationModel.setPhoto(resizeImage(event.getFile().getContents()));
}
} catch (IOException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
}
} 

public boolean validateImage(UploadedFile file)
{
if (!(file.getContentType().startsWith("image"))) {
displayErrorMessageToUser("File is not an Image file");
//System.out.println("File is not an Image file");
return false;
}
long fileByte = file.getContents().length;
if(fileByte > 102400){
//System.out.println("File size is too big (must be at most 1MB)\n");
displayErrorMessageToUser("File size is too big (must be at most 100KB)\n");
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

The above code is for file upload in primefaces. And the saving part is handled by JPA/EclipseLink.

Comment: use `JFileChooser` to select the file and use `ImageIcon` to load the file.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you be more descriptive ??

Comment: ex. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Comment: These are the basic hints that I could give. Please try google how to use the previous mentioned classes and then try to do something and if you face any problems then come back here. This is not a site where you post a question and just get a solution. You have to try it first yourself.

Comment: I have done this for single file by selecting a single file but not by selecting a whole directory.

Comment: So post your code what you tried.

Comment: Where is your code about inserting the image to database and where is the code for selecting the file? You had asked a question about inserting images to database and selecting files in directory. Please post only the relevant portions of your code and not any code to show that your have tried something.

Comment: Well my friend , saving to database is handled by JPA. I just need to handle multiple files from the directory. And above code handles only for single file upload.

Comment: Due to you bad choice of tags (java in this case) you get all kinds of 'wrong' comments/hints.